# How know number of monitor / screen on WPF as windows show on display settings

Tags: c#, wpf

Under wpf  based on what I check, there is no way to pickup number of monitor where my app is opened.
winform provide a method for discover this, but not works ok, winform method show number of monitor with no any correlation with what windows screen show.

[image]

The code I use is very simple, consist in add winform object can be any thing, then onload in wpf I just get the number of monitor in this way.

```
 numberofmonitor.Text = (Regex.Replace(System.Windows.Forms.Screen.FromControl(winformobj).DeviceName, "[^0-9]", "").ToString());


        <WindowsFormsHost Visibility="Hidden">
            <wf:MaskedTextBox x:Name="winformobj"  />
        </WindowsFormsHost>
```

This works, but this code just show the device name, not the monitor number.
I search across the web and cant find any solution for get number of monitor with exact correlation windows display setup show.
I search here on stackoverflow, but nothing I found works.
This post can look like duplicated, but nothing I found here works under windows 10, I can get device numbers but not the number of monitor in correlation as windows shows.
Some idea?

Comment: What kind of information do you actually want? The index number of monitor in display settings, which a WPF window belongs?

Comment: Hello emoacht 
Basically if I open my wpf on monitor 1, I want get 1 , if i open my wpf app on the monitor 3, then get the number of monitor what is 3, in exact correlation as windows show on display config.

Comment: Unfortunately I have never seen documentation about how the index number in the display settings is determined. You can get the display index of monitor by Win32 functions and it usually matches the index number but sometimes it doesn't. So the method is not hundred percent reliable.

Comment: Well i see some software coded in .net can doit. So should exist some way of doit in reliable way as that software. I continue researching :)
Anyway thanks for your reply.

Comment: Okay, I am also interested in how it can be done, could you direct me to the software you mentioned?

Comment: https://www.displayfusion.com/  a pure winform .net software capable of do this in proper way.