# Matching Delphi monitor indexes to Windows Desktop numbering

Tags: windows, delphi, multiple-monitors

In a multi-monitor system, the Windows Display Settings page gives each monitor a number, and an "Identify" button displays the numbers on the each monitor.

Delphi's `Screen.Monitors` array allows me to enumerate the connected monitors, but the array indices don't always match the Desktop settings above. How can I correlate the two?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67697897/how-know-number-of-monitor-screen-on-wpf-as-windows-show-on-display-settings   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11348136/how-can-i-get-monitors-numbers-from-screen-resolution-dialog-in-win7-programmati

Comment: Microsoft does not want to document the order for whatever reason.

Comment: Keep in mind that multiple (not always all) monitors can display the same content instead of one portion of the desktop, especially when one monitor is a notebook.